# group name Conflict with Groupby in linq

Tags: sql, linq

i have a Column with name group when i want use linq give me this error this in linq key word and syn-tacks error

for example

```
var b=(from a in city.tbl_family where a.group==1 select a)
```

give me error in `a.group==1`

Comment: It will give error, because it is assuming the group is a expression term. You should change it to in Method form like `var b = city.tbl_family.Where(a=> a.group == 1);`

Comment: Please show the class that is an instance of city.  I'm confused on why city has a member property/field called tbl_family.  @stiduck - you probably have answered this correctly.  Also, please use a better variable name than "a" to describe a city relationship, how about (from family in city.tbl_family).  You'll thank yourself 5 years later.

Answer (score 2):

Try to write:

```
var b=(from a in city.tbl_family where a.@group==1 select a)
```

The @ symbol let you use reserved words in C# as variable names etc. It allows you to write for example:

```
var @class = "My text";
```

Where it will give a compiler error without the @ symbol.